# More efficient than using lots of LIKE queries mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I need to query a database to find certain urls containing a certian set of criteria for example : "MY" AND "sand" in any order.

I am currently using LIKE '%MY%' AND LIKE '%Sand%' is there a btter way of executing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could try REGEXP e.g:

```
WHERE url REGEXP '(my.*sand|sand.*my)'
```

Or alternatively:

```
WHERE URL REGEXP 'my' AND url REGEXP 'sand'
```

Not sure how the speed will compare...